# compare qqplot of a sample with a reference probability distribution in R

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression, kolmogorov-smirnov

I have a weather dataset, i found a simple linear model for two columns Temperature and Humidity and  plotted the histogram of its residuals and calculated the mean and std.

```
model <- lm(Temperature..C. ~ Humidity, data = inputData)
model.res = resid(model) 
hist(model.res) 
mean(model.res)
sd(model.res)
```

I should Plot QQ-plot of residuals versus a zero-mean normal distribution with estimated std. I used Kolmogorov-Smirnov to compare a sample with a reference probability distribution but i don't know how to plot it together:

```
ks<-ks.test(model.res, "pnorm", mean=0, sd=sd(model.res)) 
qqnorm(model.res, main="qqnorm") 
qqline(model.res)
```

Data example:

```
        Temperature..C. Humidity
1          9.472222     0.89
2          9.355556     0.86
3          9.377778     0.89
4          8.288889     0.83
5          8.755556     0.83
6          9.222222     0.85
7          7.733333     0.95
8          8.772222     0.89
9         10.822222     0.82
10        13.772222     0.72
11        16.016667     0.67
12        17.144444     0.54
13        17.800000     0.55
14        17.333333     0.51
15        18.877778     0.47
16        18.911111     0.46
17        15.388889     0.60
18        15.550000     0.63
19        14.255556     0.69
20        13.144444     0.70
```

Comment: Please give an example of your input data.

Comment: @Martin Gal I added an example of data.

Comment: Could you include the data (just a few samples) in your question? Many people are uncomfortable with external links.

Comment: @Martin Gal done!

Comment: One more question: what exactly do you want to plot? KS should give you an answer if your sample follows a specific distribution, but afaik it doesn't fit a distrubition to your sample.

Comment: @Martin Gal i want to Plot QQ-plot of residuals versus a zero-mean normal distribution with estimated std.

Comment: Replace `qqline(model.res)` with `qqline(model.res, distribution=qnorm, mean=0, sd=sd(model.res))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `ggplot2`

```r
ggplot(model, aes(sample = rstandard(model))) + 
  geom_qq() + 
  stat_qq_line(dparams=list(sd=sd(model.res)), color="red") +
  stat_qq_line()
```

The red line represents the qqline with your sample sd, the blackline a sd of 1.

You did not ask for that, but you could also add a smoothed qqplot:

```
data_model <- model
data_model$theo <- unlist(qqnorm(data_model$residuals)[1])

ggplot(data_model, aes(sample = rstandard(data_model))) + 
  geom_qq() + 
  stat_qq_line(dparams=list(sd=sd(model.res)), color="red") +
  geom_smooth(aes(x=data_model$theo, y=data_model$residuals), method = "loess")
```

Comment: In first code's first line u should put model instead of data_model i assume.

Comment: Indead. Corrected my answer.